# Defining a velocity in projective geometry

Tags: special-relativity, geometry, clifford-algebra

In spacetime geometric algebra, Hestenes and Doran define a 4-velocity for a particle moving in spacetime $\mathcal{V}^{3, 1}$ by simply differentiating w.r.t. the parameter defining the curve to get $\dot{x} = \frac{dx(\tau)}{d\tau}$. They also say that their spacetime model is basically projective geometry in geometric algebra, such that the spacial euclidean position of the particle is determined by projecting the $x$ onto $\mathcal{V}^{3, 0}$ (with normalisation).

However, Doran also states that because the 0 vector in $\mathcal{V}^{4, 1}$ is not a projective point in projective geometry, and as a consequence linearity is lost. Hence, there is no geometrical significance to adding two vectors in $\mathcal{V}^{4, 1}$. But, to define a derivative, subtraction must hold.

So why is it possible to define a velocity in projective geometry as in spacetime algebra?